# WCF, WebAPI or Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm a bit confused on what to start.

My aim is to create a "background service" which will read data from an SQL-database (locally) and sent it remotely to a rest-API service (securely using SSL with POST/Get). The service will be deployed in a local Microsoft server, and will with some intervals read data from an sql server (deployed in same server), and further sent it via Https to another RESTful API.

Any suggestion what to use? WCF, Web-API or Windows Service?

Comment: Or a console application that you schedule to run (with for example Task Scheduler in Windows).

Comment: Depends on your needs.

Comment: Since it is a background service you can design it as windows service. But if you don't have a dedicated server you can think of azure web job.

Comment: The service will be deployed in a local Microsoft server, and will with some intervals read data from an sql server (deployed in same server), and further sent it via Https to another RESTful API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really not a programming question, but I'll give you an answer anyway.

It really depends on your needs and the options you have to operate your service/application.

**If you have your own server (AWS EC2, Windows server):**

- Here I'd recommend using a Windows Service as it's stable and automatically runs when Windows boots up (No matter if you're logged in or not). This is perfect when you don't want to host anything yourself, but just send data to a RESTful API.

**If you don't have your own server, but just a web host (Like Unoeuro..):**

This is a bit trickier, as WebAPI and WCF doesn't have a built-in way to do Threads the same way that Windows Services does.

- For this I'd recommend a Web API as it's more commonly used and supported overall, and it's easier to implement a RESTful API on your site if need be. To run this as a background task, I'd recommend running some sort of "Cron job" that your Webhost may have available, and then just call a page on your Web API that your service runs on.

Overall, a Windows Service is the best possible answer for you, if you need a Background service that constantly runs and shoots data to a RESTful API, however this obviously requires access to a Windows Machine and not just a Web host through IIS.

I hope this helps bringing some light onto your issue :)

Comment: Thanks Kevin, you shed some light on it. It will be deployed in same server as the SQL server is. I was worried about that windows services wont be handling SSL post to remotely restful API in easy way.